# How do I merge signals of nested tagged types?

Tags: elm

As part of the Elm app I’m building, I want to keep signals of environment changes (like resizing the window) from data changes (rendering a filterable list of models to the browser). I thought I would model these as different extensible types:

```
type WindowUpdate = Resize (Int, Int)

type DataUpdate = TagFilter Model.Tag

type Update update data = WindowUpdate update data
                        | DataUpdate update data
                        | NoOp

updates : Signal.Mailbox (Update update data)
updates = Signal.mailbox NoOp

appModel : Signal Model
appModel =
  let
    applicationUpdates = Signal.mergeMany
                       [ updates.signal

                       ]
  in
    Signal.foldp update Model.defaultModel applicationUpdates

windowUpdate : WindowUpdate -> Model -> Model
windowUpdate update model =
    let resizeWidth = \windowModel newWidth -> { windowModel | width = newWidth }
    in
      case update of
        Resize (w, _) -> { model | window = (resizeWidth model.window w) }

update : Update -> Model -> Model
update u model =
  case u of
    WindowUpdate wu data -> windowUpdate (wu data)  model
    DataUpdate du data  -> model
    otherwise       -> model
```

Unfortunately I can’t get my update function to work correctly. I get the following compiler errors:

```
— TYPE MISMATCH —————————————————————— ./app/Updates.elm

The 3rd argument to function `foldp` is causing a mismatch.

36│     Signal.foldp update Model.defaultModel applicationUpdates
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `foldp` is expecting the 3rd argument to be:

    Signal (Update a)

But it is:

    Signal Update

Hint: I always figure out the type of arguments from left to right. If an
argument is acceptable when I check it, I assume it is "correct" in subsequent checks. So the problem may actually be in how previous arguments interact with the 3rd.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the type parameters of `Update` in the signature of `update`, it should be (code untested):

`update : Update update data -> Model -> Model`

Comment: "You can't have a constructor in a type signature"… I thought (because I'd declared `WindowUpdate` as a type, that I could have it as a type in a signature? Why not?

Comment: @andrewdotnich: Sorry, I shouldn't answer SO questions when I'm sleepy :) Didn't see the type declaration, only the constructor in `type Update update data = WindowUpdate update data`.